# Accessing terminal running in background

Tags: python, terminal

I have a python script running on my rpi, which is starts from rc.local file. The script itself is working fine as it should, silently in background without opened terminal window. But in case I want to access the terminal it's running on and see the output how can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not running in any terminal, so there's nothing to see.  Terminal is an interactive program that can use to start jobs and receive output.  Programs can run other ways - For example launched from graphical desktop or via script as you have done.

Comment: Thanks but the commands to log the information to the screen, aren't they going anywhere? Any suggestion on how can I manage this? Maybe run it in a "hidden" terminal somehow and then access it later somehow?

Comment: They log to "standard out" - That's the screen if you start from a terminal without doing something special, but it can generally be anything or nothing at all.